# JSON.Net, JsonConvert.DeserializeObject - problems with deserialization

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

When I am trying to deserialize my JSON with JSON.Net it gives me invalid values for JSON arrays.

I have simple JSON:

```
[
{
    "PhaseName": "Start",
    "Advices": ["Lorem ipsum dolor",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor"]
},
{
    "PhaseName": "In Progress",
    "Advices": ["Lorem ipsum dolor",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor"]
},
{
    "PhaseName": "Finish",
    "Advices": ["Lorem ipsum dolor",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor",
    "Lorem ipsum dolor"]
}
```

]

And a correspondent class in my code:

```
public class Advices
{
    public string PhaseName { get; set; }
    public List<string> AdvicesList { get; set; }
}
```

And a veriable that represents an array of Advices objects:

```
public class MyAdvices
{
    private Advices[] MyAdvicesArrays;
....
```

So when I am trying to deserialize my JSON like that:

```
MyAdvicesArrays= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Advices[]>(sMyJSON));
```

JSON.Net populates "Phase Name" property of each object in my MyAdvicesArrays array with correct value but Advices array of each object is invalid: "Could not evaluate expression" if you check them in runtime. I don't get it. What I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're JSON is incorrect as is you Class.

First change your JSON to this:

```
{
    phases:[
        {
            "PhaseName": "Start",
            "Advices": ["Lorem ipsum dolor",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor"]
        },
        {
            "PhaseName": "In Progress",
            "Advices": ["Lorem ipsum dolor",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor"]
        },
        {
            "PhaseName": "Finish",
            "Advices": ["Lorem ipsum dolor",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor",
            "Lorem ipsum dolor"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice before you weren't declaring you JSON object correctly. Also you need a property for the array.

Now you'll need two classes:

```
public class AnythinYouWant{
    public List<Phase> Phases{get;set;}
}

public class Phase{
    public string PhaseName{get;set;}
    public List<string> Advices{get;set;}
}
```

Notice how the first class is for the top level JSON object. The name can be whatever you want. But any property needs to match the name.

Comment: Thanks, sounds logical. So does it mean that I cannot have unnamed array of objects in JSON like in my example?

[
 {
  "example": 1,
  "example2": "TestName"
 }, 
 
 {
  "example3": 1,
  "example4": "TestName" } 
]

Comment: no you can't, because your json object must always begin with {}, you can't declare it with []. After the initial {} you have to have a property to assign your first array.

Answer (score 1):

Your `json` is not valid according to the entities.

In your type change `AdvicesList` to `Advices`.

```
public List<string> AdvicesList { get; set; }
```

Change it to

```
public List<string> Advices { get; set; }
```

Comment: "Advices" in my example supposed to be an object with string property and array property, how could it be List<string>?

Answer (score 0):

All I did to get this working was to change the definition of the `Advices` class:

```
public class Advice
{
    public string PhaseName { get; set; }
    public List<string> Advices { get; set; }
}
```

I changed the class name to just `Advice` and `AdvicesList` property to `Advices`.

Comment: I don't understand, what have you changed except for class name and property name? The class definition is still the same.